# Cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (nginx + passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm stuck on migration Rails app from one server to another. Collected some pains though.
Here's what error log says:

```
[ 2017-06-06 08:23:48.6548 8417/7ff9d22e1700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/deploy/www: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: c5a05c55
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-3XW0L6.html
  Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Config so far:

**Passenger**:

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/wrappers/ruby;
```

Nginx:

```
include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Nginx virtual server:

```
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

server_name [ip_address_of_my_server];

access_log /var/log/nginx/eco-klinker.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/eco-klinker.error.log;

passenger_enabled on;
rails_env production;
root /home/deploy/www/public;
```

App folder:

```
deploy@73704:~/www$ ls
app  bin  config  config.ru  db  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  lib  log  public  Rakefile  README.rdoc  test  tmp  vendor
```

I am pretty sure the problem lies between passenger and nginx configs, because I am able to do stuff with rails like: bundle install, rails c production.
I've went through many similiar posts here, but nothing worked out yet. Please help.

UPD. I just created new rails app, but still getting the same error.

Comment: `gem install bundler` ?

Comment: tried
`bundle -v`
`Bundler version 1.15.1`

Comment: is the ruby version on the new server 2.3.0?

Comment: @MarcusHoile Yes, it is `ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: ls `/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/` ?

Comment: @Ben, not sure what is your question, but yes, there is that directory with ruby versions: 
`cache       ruby-2.3.0@eco     ruby-2.4.0
ruby-2.3.0  ruby-2.3.0@global  ruby-2.4.0@global`